# Performance Issue With Join and Dates

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to left join two tables which has around 870,000 records (each table). 
I have to join on date and varchar fields.
I know this is the worst combination. 
I tried converting Date Fields to int and also indexing all columns i am joining in both the tables. 
This query is taking for ever.

I want a report for daily sliced by counties.

Is there any other way of doing this?

```
select  
    distinct 
     [MemberID]
    , [AuthID]
    , f.[Carrier]
    , null As  [County]
    , [ServiceStatus]
    , null  As [ZipCode]
    , [DischargedDate]
    , f.[RequestType]
    , [ProviderNPI]
    , [ProviderName]
    , [Discipline]
    , f.[Market]
    , f.[Phase]
    , f.[DateValue]
    , [UnitsAllowed]
    , [CompletedVisits]
    ,COALESCE(f.[ForeCastVisits], '0') AS ForeCastVisits,f.[Is_holiday] AS IsHoliday
,f.[is_weekday] AS IsWeekday,    f.[MyNexus_is_Holiday] AS MyNexusIsHoliday
,f.DaysOfTheWeek 
    , [ApprovedDate] 
    ,DateFlag 
    into #utiltable
  from #forecastValue f  
left outer join #UtilizationData u
on f.datevalue=u.DailyDate
and f.market=u.market
and f.Phase=u.Phase
and f.Carrier=u.Carrier
and f.ServiceRequestType=u.ServiceRequestType
and f.county=u.county
```

Comment: remove the distinct to start with, unless it's absolutely necessary. That's causing a sort operation. You have temp tables here... did you create the index after or before you put the data into the temp tables? Also, why did you use temp tables to begin with? perhaps you can query the base table directly

Comment: I need distinct here. I created index after putting data into my table. I have many aggregations to be performed .. after all calculations I put the data into temp tables for my final join

Comment: It’s help to see all the code then to speed it up